# Boost equivalent of memcpy?

Tags: c++, c, boost

Is there a boost equivalent for memcpy?  Thanks!

**EDIT:** Sorry, I didn't realize memcpy was in the standard library :) 
I thought it was an OS call :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Does there need to be one? What's wrong with `memcpy`? Although it comes from C, it's a perfectly valid C++ function. If you want something that's aware of C++ objects and their assignment operators, then use [`std::copy`](http://dinkumware.com/manuals/?manual=compleat&page=algorith.html#copy). You might also want to take a look at [`std::uninitialized_copy`](http://dinkumware.com/manuals/?manual=compleat&page=memory.html#uninitialized_copy).

Comment: Indeed.  memcpy( ) doesn't care what it's copying; objects, arrays, whatever.  It's all bytes.